Why is my state variable not updating inside of my socket.on call in useeffect?
I've looked through various posts and this is currently the most updated version of my code, but the problem is my state variable tlofFatoData doesn't seem to be updating in the socket.on call (it stays the same value each event reception). I need the latest value to use in my call to animateFatoTlofFlight(key) after since I am also referencing tlofFatoData in that function. I've also tried using a useRef for tlofFatoData instead but that doesn't seem to fix it. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong?
useEffect(() => {
    
    const handleUpdate = async (data) => {
      console.log("Socket event received:", data);
      const status = data['status'];

      // Update tlofFatoData directly from the socket event
      const fetchedData = await fetchTlofFato();
      //tlofFatoData.current = fetchedData;
      setTlofFatoData(oldData => ({
        ...oldData,
        ...fetchedData
      }));
      console.log("tlofFatoData in socket.on is ", tlofFatoData);
  

      Object.keys(status).forEach(key => {
          console.log('status is ', status);
          updateStatuses(status, key);
          
          if (!(key in animatedACs.current)) {
              animatedACs.current[key] = { ...status[key] };
          }

          if (status[key].hasOwnProperty('ac_status')) {
              console.log("ac_status is ", status[key].ac_status);
              if (status[key].ac_status === 'landed' && !animatedACs.current[key].hasOwnProperty('hasCalledAnimate')) {
                  var tempMap = new Map(remainingEnergyRef.current);
                  tempMap.set(key, status[key].remainingEnergy);
                  console.log('remaining energy is ' + tempMap);
                  remainingEnergyRef.current = new Map(tempMap);
                  animateFatoTlofFlight(key);
              } else if (status[key].ac_status === 'left' && !animatedACs.current[key].hasOwnProperty('hasCalledAnimate')) {
                  var tempMap = new Map(remainingEnergyRef.current);
                  tempMap.set(key, "N/A");
                  console.log('remaining energy is ' + tempMap);
                  remainingEnergyRef.current = new Map(tempMap);
                  animateFatoTlofFlight(key);
              }
          } else {
              console.log("ac status not found");
          }
      });
    };

    if (updatedRoute && tlofFatoData) {
        console.log('updatedRoute is ', updatedRoute);
        animatedACs.current = Object.assign({}, tlofFatoData);
        console.log('animated Acs is ', animatedACs.current);
        console.log("inside of tloffatodata");

        socket.on('AAM_AC_Update', handleUpdate);

        // Cleanup function
        return () => {
            socket.off('AAM_AC_Update', handleUpdate);
        };
    }
}, [updatedRoute, tlofFatoData]);

  //fetch the data regarding tlof and fato locations
  const fetchTlofFato = async () => {
    try {
        const fetchedData = await fetchTlofFatoData(); // Call the exported function
       // console.log('fetchedData is ',fetchedData);
        return fetchedData;
        // if (JSON.stringify(tlofFatoData) !== JSON.stringify(fetchedData)) {
        //   // settlofFatoData(fetchedData); // Set the data in component state;
        //   tlofFatoData = fetchedData;
        //   console.log("tlofFatoData is", tlofFatoData);
        // }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        return null;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const data = await fetchTlofFato();
      setTlofFatoData(data);
      //tlofFatoData = data;
      //setTlofFatoData(data);
    };
  
    getData();
  }, []);

I tried changing the variable tlofFatoData to a useRef. I've also tried updating the fetchTlofFatoData function to return the value and set the state inside the socket.on call instead of inside the function. I'm expecting tlofFatoData to have the latest updated value from the fetch call so that it can be used for the animateFatoTlofFlight function within the same socket.on event.

In the log statement aren’t you trying to access the state immediately after calling set on it? If you want to act on the new state immediately either create a temp or use the callback (if that’s still a thing)

see also

@DaveNewton State callback is not still a thing. FWIW the old this.setState callback was determined to be more of a/an foot-gun/anti-pattern as it caused more issues than it solved. Just imagine the absurdity of debugging a chain of setState callbacks that keep enqueuing more state updates. The useState hook's state updater function provides no such callback.

@DrewReese Good to know; thx—didn’t think it was but not JS-y lately
